# Direct sum of kernel for polynomials of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T: V \rightarrow V$ and $P_1, P_2, Q_1, Q_2$ are polynomials such that $P_1(T)Q_1(T) + P_2(T)Q_2(T) = I$ and suppose $P_1(T)P_2(T) = 0$. Show $V = \text{ker}~P_1(T) \bigoplus \text{ker}~P_2(T)$.

I have worked out that $P_1$ and $P_2$ have to be coprime which would imply that $ker ~P_1(T)$ and $ker~P_2(T)$ are disjoint. Furthermore, I have verified that $ker ~P_1(T) = im~P_2(T)$. How do I finish this off?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that since these are polynomials in one variable, you may change the order in which they are activated.

Now you can use the first and second equations to establish the following:

$\forall v: P_1(T)Q_1(T)v\in\ker P_2(T)$ and symmetrically for 2,1.

Using the first equation you can finish proving what you want. Finally, to show that the sum is direct, suppose $w$ is in the intersection and put it through the first equation (using the property mentioned at the top).

Comment: For any $w$, you have $P_2(T)P_1(T)w=0$. Substitute $w=Q_1(T)v$.